# Overriding SELECT behavior of Enter key

Tags: javascript, select

Working on a HTML control that more/less operates like a spreadsheet - with a matrix of editable data cells. When it comes to cells derived from a SELECT I'm having an issue getting the correct behavior when that type of cell is selected for edit:

If I render the Select using its default formatting (size = 0) then the user gets the out-of-place behavior of Select's Enter-key processing:

- 1st Enter => activates editing on the cell (shows the select control)
- 2nd Enter => expands the Select to show the Options
- user makes selection using up/dn keys
- 3rd Enter => closes the list. (Problem: this Enter is hidden from "keydown" event handler)
- 4th Enter => required to trigger the event listener for deactivating cell edit.

On the other hand, if the select is rendered as a listbox (ie, size = 3, for example) the Enter key behavior is exactly what I'm looking for (meaning, #2 and #3 on the above list are no longer required), but because the list is now displayed internally to the control (rather than as a pop-up) it blows up the cell/row sizing.

So, is there a way to "hook" into the 3rd Enter-key event above, or some other relatively straight-forward way to alter the Select's behavior when it comes to processing the Enter key?

NOTE: we are not using any 3rd party library (read: jQuery, et. al)

EDIT: here is the event listener (attached via typical "addEventListener(...)"

```
this.e_sKeyDown = function(control, event) {
  switch(event.keyCode) {
    case 13:  // enter
      control.blur()
      break
    case 27:  // esc = reset selection to it previous value
      control.setAttribute("data-cancelModify", "true")
      control.blur()
      break
  }
}
```

2nd EDIT: per comments/suggestions, I've added/given this try:

```
this.e_sOnChange = function(control, event) {
  control.blur()
}
```

That event will fire, but it fires for each of the different Option/s. In other words, it doesn't appear that I'll have any way to determine if that is the Option that the user actually *intended* for selection, or just one that was traversed along the way. To demonstrate, here is any example for jquery's site. Note how the text changes with each up/down, regardless of Enter-key:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

SOLVED: thanks to all the commenters for their suggestions. Indeed, the solution (for my situation anyway) was to add a "keyup" event listener into the mix. I can't say what browsers this will work in, but it is functional in the later versions of Chrome.

Comment: 3rd enter => `onchange`, perhaps?

Comment: Why is the third enter hidden from the `keydown` handler?

Comment: onChange... thanks, I'll look into that. Justin: I have no idea, all I can say is that the event is not trigger with the Select is in its expanded sate. I will post event handler.

Comment: So let me see if I understand...the problem is that the `keydown` event isn't firing when the listbox is open? That's what it sounds like. Throw a `keydown` listener on the whole document and see if it's popping up on a different element than you think. I don't know how to do this without jQuery, sorry.

Comment: OTOH, if @JanDvorak's `onchange` idea works, I say go with that.

Comment: In essence Yes - I'm not sure if it's even supposed to (given the loose spec on Enter processing behavior) or whether I'm looking at some type of "interference"

Comment: in general, I have seen "custom selects" implemented with floating divs or whatever

Comment: I've given the onChange handler a go, but it's getting triggered on *each* record of the option list - whether that's the one intended for selection, or not...

Comment: There is always `keyup` too. I have found when trying to capture key events that `keyup` has always been the best for cross-browser compatibility. Not sure if it'll be the fix for you, but it is worth a shot, right?

Comment: @jesus.tesh - bingo. Just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per suggestions, the way to pick up the "hidden" Enter-key event is to add a "keyup" event listener; question has been edited to reflect the solution.

**NOTE:** this answer was only posted to close the question; please give credit where it is due - jesus.tesh and the rest of the commenters for their suggestions...