# How can I make the Enter key submit a form while a select field is focussed, without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, forms

When a `<select>` field is focussed, pressing the Enter key does not submit the form. Is it possible to make it submit the form, without using JavaScript?

A solution working in quirks mode is fine, too.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360402/what-is-unclear-about-my-question-is-stackoverflow-se-going-to-do-something-a)

Comment: @John You may be interested in reading about accessibility, aria, screen readers and the likes. There is nothing intuitive about a return submitting a form when focusing on a select field (the return is generally used to select one of the options).

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to alter this behaviour without using JavaScript. According to the discussion at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155863/overriding-select-behavior-of-enter-key), capturing the `keyup` event is the best option for browser compatibility.

You may want to reconsider altering this behaviour, as discussed at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968693/why-doesnt-hitting-enter-when-a-select-is-focused-submit-the-form) you may surprise your users by doing so.